# How to integrate rate-limiter-flexible in existing node.js express setup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rate-limiting

I use node.js, passport and jwt bearer token to protect my routes. What I don't have yet is rate limiting and blocking of ip/user if too many false attempts. What's the best way to implement it for my setup?

I want to give it a try with rate-limiter-flexible. But how can I integrate e.g. the Login Example from here: https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Overall-example#login-endpoint-protection in my setup below?

helpers/rateLimiter.js

```
const express = require('express');
const redis = require('redis');
const { RateLimiterRedis } = require('rate-limiter-flexible');

/* What goes here? Example https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Overall-example#login-endpoint-protection doesn't seem to apply */
```

Those are my routes:

routes/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = require('express-promise-router')();
const passport = require('passport');
const passLogin = passport.authenticate('local-login', { session: false, failWithError: true });
const { rateLimiter } = require('../helpers/rateLimiter');
...

router.route('/v1/login')
    .post( rateLimiter, passLogin, function(err, req, res, next) {
        return res.status(401).send({ status: 401, success: false })
}, controller.login );

router.route('/v1/abc/search')
    .post( passJWT_ABC, function(err, req, res, next) {
        return res.status(401).send({ status: 401, success: false })
}, controller.search );
```

Comment: How do you use `passport`? It is imported, but not used.

Comment: @Animir Please see above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should export middleware in this case.

```js
const express = require('express');
const redis = require('redis');
const { RateLimiterRedis } = require('rate-limiter-flexible');

async function loginRoute(req, res) {
   // code from example https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Overall-example#login-endpoint-protection
}

export default async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await loginRoute(req, res);
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).end();
  }
}
```

And then you should take care of how `authorise()`, `user.isLoggedIn` and `user.exists` checks work with your application login approach.

There is an example with passport-local, should be useful for you as well https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/67e0f735fc6d2088d7aa9b8c4eb25bc0052653ec/server-secure.js

Comment: Thanks for the post and the example. I'll give it a try!